# Init a big constant datastructure in Android

Tags: android, compiler-errors

I have to init a big constant data structure but I get the compiler error message:

```
The code of constructor MS_XXX(String) is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit
```

This is how the code may looks like:

```
   public class MD_XXX {

        public List<String> allElements; 

        public MD_XXX(String language) {
            this.allElements = new ArrayList<String>();


            if (...) {
                /* 0 */    allElements.add("some text0");
                /* 1 */    allElements.add("some text1");
                /* 2 */    allElements.add("some text2");
 .. many more lines here
```

BUT

I also have much more data structures to initialize, putting this into a DB is a real hassle - and again, this is confidential info.

What is the best way to solve this?
Do I really have to break this up into several class files or read it from a DB?
I really try to avoid the DB way, since this data should be secure to the app.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I really have to break this up into several class files

It is probably sufficient to split it into several *methods*. Add some private methods that you call from that super-long constructor and move parts of the code there. Each method can be 65535 bytes long.

Comment: yes you are right - fortunately - thanks very much. But this is really  a disappointment. In iPhone programming with XCode this works without any problem.